# Adding google link tracking to blog post URL redirects to home page

Tags: joomla-3.x, google-analytics

I'm coming across a strange issue - when adding google analytics link tracking code to a blog post URL it redirects to the home page rather than the blog post, without the GA tracking details the post loads fine.

The original link looks like:

https://www.website.com/blog/90-need-a-translator-we-don-t-just-talk-the-talk?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog_17may18

However, if I set the campaign parameters in the fragment portion of the URL so that the URL looks like:

https://www.website-it.com/blog/90-need-a-translator-we-don-t-just-talk-the-talk#utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog_17may18

i.e. using a # instead of a ? - then the link lands correctly on the blog post.

I cannot seem to find any posts relating to this either on here or in Google. Has anyone seen anything like this before? Is this a known issue as google recommends not to set the campaign parameters in the fragment portion of the url.

Any ideas/information would be most appreciated.

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: Have you got any SEO extensions installed that could be overriding how Joomla is handling URLs?  Are you using Joomla's core blog, or a third party extension?
I can't replicate your issue with core Joomla.

Comment: Hi Richard, no..I have checked all of these, there are no SEO extensions in use and the core blog is being used. I have checked the htacess file and the redirects/REDJ components to no avail. I have asked the client to use the # for the time being while I investigate - this is certainly a strange one for me.